# How to track the flow of data from a Vue component to a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have a text input box along with 2 images attached to a 'Case File', I can see when I type in the box that the data contains in my message input in the same array as the images. But when I view this data in my Rails Model, the message input is nowhere to be found, just the images are attached.

I'm probably not submitting the text input properly, but I'm not quite sure how I would approach this, as I can't follow the data flow that the photos are taking, if for some reason the text portion in the same array doesn't flow with them, however I am quite inexperienced with Vue. I'll attach what I believe to be relevant files below, and would appreciate any pointers.

AttachmentEditForm.vue

```
    <template>
  <section class="p-1">
    <b-switch
      v-model="attachmentAccepted"
      :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
    >
      {{attachmentAcceptedLabel}}
    </b-switch>

    <template v-if="attachmentAccepted">
      <b-field
        :label="t('document_type')"
      >
        <b-select
          v-model="documentType"
          icon="file-alt"
          :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
        >
          <optgroup
            v-for="group in allDocumentTypeGroups"
            :key="group.id"
            :label="t(group.name)"
          >
            <option
              v-for="type in group.documentTypes"
              :key="type.id"
              :value="type.id"
            >
              {{t(type.name)}}
            </option>
          </optgroup>
        </b-select>
      </b-field>
      <b-field>
        <b-checkbox
          v-model="approveAttachment"
          :disabled="waiting.updateAttachment"
        >
          {{ t('tickets.approved') }}
        </b-checkbox>
      </b-field>
      <template v-if="attachmentAccepted && documentType && approveAttachment">
        <label class="label">{{t('case_files')}}</label>
        <document-checkbox
          v-for="cf in currentTicketCaseFiles"
          :key="cf.id"
          :case-file="cf"
          :attachment="attachment"
        />
      </template>
      <template v-if="approveAttachment">
        <textarea v-model="message"></textarea>
      </template>
      <button class="input" :click="submit"> Submit </button>
    </template>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import { mapServerActions } from "../../../../../../_frontend_infrastructure/javascript/lib/crudvuex_new";
import DocumentCheckbox from './DocumentCheckbox';
import AttachmentTypeMixin from './mixins/AttachmentTypeMixin';

export default {
  name: 'AttachmentEditForm',
  mixins: [AttachmentTypeMixin],
  components: { DocumentCheckbox },
  props: {
    attachment: Object,
    slideIndex: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      waiting: {},
      message: "",
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allDocumentTypeGroups', 'currentTicketCaseFiles', 'activeAttachmentIndex', 'showAttachmentsPreview', 'activeAttachments']),

    attachmentAcceptedLabel() {
      return this.attachmentAccepted ? this.t('accepted') : this.t('ignored');
    },
    attachmentAccepted: {
      get: function () {
        return !this.attachment.ignoreAttachment;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]);
      },
    },
    documentType: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.documentTypeId;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { documentTypeId: val }]);
      },
    },
    approveAttachment: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.approvedAttachment;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { approvedAttachment: val }]);
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapServerActions(['updateAttachment']),
    ...mapMutations(['changeActiveAttachmentIndex', 'closeAttachmentsPreview']),

    submit() {
      console.log(this.props.attachment);
    },

    processAttachmentPreviewOpen() {
      if (this.showAttachmentsPreview && this.slideIndex === this.activeAttachmentIndex) {
        if (this.isImage(this.attachment) && !this.approveAttachment) {
          this.approveAttachment = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeAttachmentIndex() {
      this.processAttachmentPreviewOpen();
    },
    'attachment.documents.length'(value) {
      let isAttachmentFullyProcessed =
        this.attachmentAccepted && this.documentType && this.approveAttachment && value > 0;

      if (isAttachmentFullyProcessed && this.currentTicketCaseFiles.length === 1) {
        let maxPossibleIndex = (this.activeAttachments.length - 1);

        if (this.activeAttachmentIndex < maxPossibleIndex) {
          setTimeout(() => this.changeActiveAttachmentIndex(this.activeAttachmentIndex + 1), 500);
        } else {
          this.$buefy.toast.open({
            message: 'All attachments were processed!',
            type: 'is-success'
          });
          setTimeout(() => this.closeAttachmentsPreview(), 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.processAttachmentPreviewOpen();
  }
};
</script>
```

CcVAttachmentsModel.rb

```
    class CcVAttachment < CcContext
  include Attachable

  CONTENT_TYPES = %w[image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/tiff application/pdf text/plain].freeze

  belongs_to :message, class_name: 'CcMessage', foreign_key: :parent_idx
  belongs_to :document_type
  has_one :ticket, through: :message
  has_many :message_attachments, class_name: 'CcVDocument', foreign_key: :parent_id
  configure_storage(:cc_v_attachments, name: :content)
  validates_attachment :content, content_type: { content_type: CONTENT_TYPES }
end
```

cc_v_attachmentsController.rb

```
    module Panel
  class CcVAttachmentsController < CcVEntitiesBaseController
    def update
      run 'ccenter.cc_v_attachments.update'
    end

    private

    def ticket_model
      CcVAttachment.find(params[:id]).ticket
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What I'd suggest is taking a look at what's sent to the Rails API. The easiest way to do this is probably using `byebug` (if you've not used `byebug`, this is a gem that lets you add breakpoints to your code and get an interactice REPL at the breakpoint). You could then inspect the `params` that reach your Rails controller and see what's there and how it's formatted.

Comment: Along with what JohnP said, you should also check your browser's Network tab and see what params are being sent in the request itself.